# Flask site works with SQlite but breaks when connecting to Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

My site is essentially a blog site -- a user uploads a post and each post has tags that categorize it. I build the site using a SQlite db and when I switched to Postgres I started getting this error when uploading a new post:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely)
(psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character varying(20)
```

```
@posts.route('/post/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(title=form.title.data, description=form.description.data, author=current_user)
        if form.notebook.data:

            picture_file = save_notebook(form.notebook.data)#set user profile picture
            post.notebook_file = picture_file

            #Save tag data into database
            for tag in form.tags.data:
                post_tag = add_tags(tag)
                post.tags.append(post_tag)

            # ADDING NOTEBOOK HTML TO POST AS STRING
            notebook_path_str = url_for('static',
                                        filename='notebooks/' + picture_file)  # STRING (src="{{ notebook }}")
            notebook_html_str = open('/Users/colestriler/coding/websites/Flask_Blog/flaskapp' + notebook_path_str)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(notebook_html_str, 'html.parser')
            post.notebook_html = str(soup.body.contents[1])  # findChildren() removes body tags

        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()

        print(post.tags)

        flash('Your post has been created!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='New Post', form=form, legend='New Post')


def add_tags(tag):
    existing_tag = Tags.query.filter_by(name = tag.lower()).one_or_none()
    if existing_tag is not None:
        return existing_tag
    else:
       new_tag = Tags(name=tag.lower())
       return new_tag
```

I suspect the problem might be in `add_tags()` or in `db.session.commit()`.

Here is the Post & Tags model for reference:

```
class Post(db.Model): #one-to-many relationship because 1 user can have multiple posts, but post can have 1 author
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow) #pass in function as argument (utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    notebook_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.ipynb')  # hash unique image files each 20 chars long
    notebook_type = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='Jupyter Notebook')
    notebook_html = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, default='No Notebook File')
    tags = db.relationship('Tags', secondary=relationship_table, backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"


class Tags(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
```

I cannot figure out why my code is giving me this `DataError`. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to update your `notebook_file` and `notebook_type` to be of type `db.Text`, unless you really need the constraint (in which case you can add a `CHECK` constraint to your database.  Also, `varchar(N)` is [often not recommended](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6771640) (there are many other similar blog articles).  Also, in SQLite, `varchar(N)` is not [really enforced](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html), which may explain why you were able to get away with no errors previously.

Otherwise, please update your original post with proof that you are getting the error message while not attempting to enter a `notebook_file` or `notebook_type` with greater than 20 chars.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: That was it. Changed from String to Text and it worked. Thank you very much.